# Need help clicking on a selector with no name or id

Tags: puppeteer

```
<a _ngcontent-obv-c97 class="a-center pointer">เพิ่มเติม</a>
```

This is how the html looks like,

I've tried something like:

```
await page.click(".a-center pointer");

await page.click('a[class="a-center.pointer"]');

await page.evaluate(()=>document.querySelector('.a-center pointer').click());
```

but none worked, sorry in advance I'm quite new to puppeteer, any help is much appreciated.